# white screen after present an UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm presenting an `UIImagePickerController` to take a photo, the problem is if I take a photo, or cancel the `UIImagePickerController` I'll return on a white screen and not on my previous `ViewController`. Only my `navigation bar` still here. If I click to an other `view` (with the navigation bar) it's ok, and if I return on the tab where the `UIImagePickerController` is called it still white.

```
 let picker = UIImagePickerController();
 picker.delegate = self;
 picker.mediaTypes = [swiftString];
 picker.allowsEditing = true

 picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
 picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
 self.present(picker, animated:true, completion:nil);
```

**dismiss** :

```
picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil);

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil);
}
```

If someone have an idea thank's !

**Update** :

White screen appears always when i call a view  with `present method`. So i think it's conflict with the navigation controller (hierarchy...)

This solve my problem :

```
guard let appDelegate =  UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}
appDelegate.navigationController.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If someone have an other alternative to solve it !

Comment: How you are dismissing `UIImagePickerController` ?

Comment: @Poles Of course, post is edited to show it

Comment: Are you sure you made your class a subclass of UINavigationControllerDelegate which is required by the image picker?

Answer (score 2):

Use `picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext` before presenting the imagepicker.

Comment: This make my view completely out, every button are not working and the picker isn't presented.

Comment: Ok.  Use `imagePicker.parent?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` while dismissing imagepicker.

Comment: The problem isn't from the picker, i've investigate in the app and it's always i use present method. It's like a conflict between present and the navigationController

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I use for the camera:

```
func openCameraApp() {
    if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModes(for: .rear) != nil {
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(picker,
                animated: true,
                completion: nil)
    } else {
        noCamera()
    }
}
func noCamera(){
    let alertVC = UIAlertController(
        title: "No Camera",
        message: "Sorry, this device has no camera",
        preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(
        title: "OK",
        style:.default,
        handler: nil)
    alertVC.addAction(okAction)
    present(
        alertVC,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage  // do you have this line in your code?
    image = chosenImage
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowEditView", sender: self)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

I notice a couple of things different.

- You set `.allowsEditing` to true. I don't believe that is making a difference.
- I'm checking for a camera, but you probably didn't put that code in your question.
- I'm setting `.modalPresentationStyle` to full screen. This could be your issue.
- I don't see the `imagePickerController(picker: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo)` call. But since it shouldn't build, that definitely isn't the issue.
- Inside that call I unwrap the image from `info`. **I believe this is your issue.** I've placed a comment on that specific line, asking you to check for this.
- Finally, I'm executing a segue to another view controller. (My app is basically a "select" then "edit".)

Comment: Hello, thank's for your help but it change nothing. i'll update the post, the problem come from call present method with my navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

Set the `.modalPresentationStyle` to fullScreen